# What is the query builder in firebase firestore and what's its use cases?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is that **query builder** which is shown on the Firebase Firestore page, what's its use case and how does it benefit my project?

[image: Firestore query builder]

From the documentation, I get that it's used to query collections and sub-collections in that actual Firestore database.

But does this used just for visualizing the queries from it? or does it prepare those types of queries to be ready when requesting them so it will cause some performance and speed of requesting improvements?

and when should I use it, and when I shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new query building in the Firestore console is just a visual way to build a query that then determines what data the console shows. I find it most helpful to limit the amount of data the console shows, and to see if a query is going to be possible before I translate it in to code.

Aside from that, the query build shows the resulting documents in a tabular view (rather than the panel view that already existed), which makes it possible to compare documents at a glance and fits more data in less space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This feature can really help with complex queries.

Comment: I haven't gotten that far into complex queries with it yet, but that's indeed what I imagine. 